If electrically charged particles transact virtual photons, why aren't said virtual photons subject to the rules of general and special relativity?
For instance, if there exists an electron at sea level, and an electron in orbit, why don't the virtual photons which mediate their electrical field contract and expand as they move across the intermediate gravitational gradient?

In general virtual photons are just a name ... physicists have no testable model for what is occurring in space between charged particles.  Science probably will  never know .... its a great mystery just like why are we here.

Most importantly, are quantum particles subject to relativity?

@Ritzthephysibeast yes, this is covered in quantum field theory, at least at the special relativity level. And one can add curved spacetime in certain situations. It's exactly why muons survive to the surface of the earth from the top of the atmosphere.

Virtual particles are not real particles, and they are not subject to the constraints on real particles (virtual particles are "off-shell"). Indeed there's an argument that virtual particles are no more than a mathematical convenience for describing the electromagnetic field.
It's also not clear why you think that virtual particles don't "contract or expand", nor what physical consequences you think this would have.

The problem is that science has so far shown no interest in describing the electric or magnetic field in structural terms. Roughly from a mechanistic point of view:

between electric charges of the same name, the electric field is elastic and displaces each other. The “ends” of the fields of two electrons cannot interact with each other. With such an approach, the crutch of the virtual photon is no longer necessary.
when different elementary charges approach each other, the electric field decreases, emitting electromagnetic radiation. Since the radiation is quantized, the field should also be modelled as consisting of particles.

As long as there is neither scientific curiosity nor economic interest in the structure of fields, it will remain with virtual photons, which “never do not exist but are good for describing a process that has not been studied in detail”.
